# Binarization of an image with uneven lighting

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary-image

I am trying to binarize the following image, which is not taken under ideal laboratory conditions as light isn't uniform across it.[image]

My goal is to get a result which will display the background of the image as white, and the droplets on the background as black. I am using the following code in order to achieve this:

```
RGB = imread('digital.jpg'); %% read image in the workspace
Image_gray=rgb2gray(RGB);
Image_gray = imadjust(Image_gray,stretchlim(Image_gray),[0 1]);
bw=imbinarize(Image_gray);
imshow(~Image_gray);
```

The result which I am getting is the following:

[image]

Any idea on how the image could be more appropriately processed in order to get a more uniform result (i.e the droplets to be black no matter the shade on them)?

Comment: Do you have control over the setup and lighting?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes I have, but it is tricky as the camera taking the image that needs to be binarized will be placed on a "robot". Theoretically I could put on a light next to the camera to make the image more uniform, but it makes the setup really complex.

Comment: What is your exact purpose? I was able to find many of the droplets using https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html

Comment: @Durkee So what I am trying to do is to detect the hydrophobicity of a surface (in my case an HV insulator). There are a lot of parameters which can be used for determining this, such as the percentage of the area covered by water (More water means less hydrophobic). To do that, we need the image to be binarized, and after that the estimation is pretty easy. But if the droplets can't be exactly binarized (as in the whole droplet being represented by black and not just some of it), the result won't be accurate.

Comment: I feel like this could be better tested if you weighed the surface before and after dropping water on it. Because even with this, you're not testing the total amount of water, you're testing the area of the water. Whereas weight will test how much water is actually on the surface.

Comment: Because of the nature of the experiment, that is not possible. The only possible way is to evaluate characteristics of the water droplets on the surface. Another parameter which can be used is the estimation of how round the droplets are. This still can't be achieved without accurate binarization.